# Небуферизованный ввод в консольное приложение на Swift

Tags: swift, input, консоль

Добрый день, я хочу сделать следующее: принять от пользователя ввод в консоль без нажатия клавиши Enter. 
Пишу реализацию змейки в консоли, а для управления необходимо вводить символы ("w","a","s","d"), но необходимость нажатия Enter сильно тормозит процесс игры. 
Как можно реализовать такое в Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение, которое я нашел, выглядит так:

```
func getKeyPress () -> Int
{
    var key: Int = 0
    let c: cc_t = 0
    let cct = (c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c) // Set of 20 Special Characters
    var oldt: termios = termios(c_iflag: 0, c_oflag: 0, c_cflag: 0, c_lflag: 0, c_cc: cct, c_ispeed: 0, c_ospeed: 0)

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt) // 1473
    var newt = oldt
    newt.c_lflag = 1217  // Reset ICANON and Echo off
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt)
    key = Int(getchar())  // works like "getch()"
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt)
    return key
}
```

Возвращает, очевидно, код клавиши.